# unable to use nsurlconnection in another method ios

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I have used the NSURLConnection in the below way in my app. But when I am trying to do the same in another method of the same class, the connection does not get established. I am not getting any error. When debugged, I saw that the program does not go into the below code. Please help.

EDIT:

```
if ([self hasInternetConnection] || [self hasWiFi] || [self canReachHost:@"http://myservice.asmx"]) {
        NSLog(@"Refreshing...");

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *defaultPhoneNumber = [defaults objectForKey:@"PhoneNumber"];

        NSString *xmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<ServiceCalls><ServiceCall><Phone_No>%@</Phone_No></ServiceCall></ServiceCalls>", defaultPhoneNumber];
        xmlString = [xmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@"&lt;"];
        xmlString = [xmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@"&gt;"];

        NSLog(@"%@", xmlString);

        //NSString *xmlString = @"&lt;?xml version=\"1.0\"?&gt;&lt;ServiceCalls&gt;&lt;ServiceCall&gt;&lt;Phone_No&gt;03102497593&lt;/Phone_No&gt;&lt;/ServiceCall&gt;&lt;/ServiceCalls&gt;";

        NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                 @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                                 "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                                 "<soap:Body>\n"
                                 "<GetVehiclesByPhone_ServiceCall_Proc xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                                 "<xmlStr>%@</xmlStr>\n"
                                 "<m_LoginId>%@</m_LoginId>\n"
                                 "<m_pass>%@</m_pass>\n"
                                 "</GetVehiclesByPhone_ServiceCall_Proc>\n"
                                 "</soap:Body>\n"
                                 "</soap:Envelope>\n", xmlString, @"User", @"pass"];

        NSLog(@"soapMessage: \n%@",soapMessage);

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myservice.asmx"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0f];
        NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

        [request1 addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request1 addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/GetVehiclesByPhone_ServiceCall_Proc" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
        [request1 addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request1 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request1 setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];

        NSLog(@"%@", request1);

        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request1 queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data1, NSError *error) {

            if (data1 != nil) {
                if ([data1 length] > 0 && error == nil) {
                    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data1 bytes] length:[data1 length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    theXML = [theXML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;" withString:@"<"];
                    theXML = [theXML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&gt;" withString:@">"];
                    NSLog(@"THE XML= %@",theXML);
                    NSData *receivedData = [theXML dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:receivedData];
                    xmlParser.delegate = (id)self;
                    [xmlParser parse];

                    NSString *delete = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM Vehicles"];

                    char *err;

                    if (sqlite3_exec(db, [delete UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) == SQLITE_OK) {
                        for (NSObject *currentObject in entries) {
                            NSLog(@"Entries: %@", [currentObject valueForKey:@"vrn"]);
                            NSString *insert = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Vehicles VALUES ('%@', '%@', '%@' , '%@')", [currentObject valueForKey:@"vrn"], [currentObject valueForKey:@"make"], [currentObject valueForKey:@"model"], [currentObject valueForKey:@"yearMade"]];
                            if (sqlite3_exec(db, [insert UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK) {
                                sqlite3_close(db);
                                NSAssert(0, @"Could not update table");
                                [defaults setInteger:0 forKey:@"DataExists"];
                            }
                            else {
                                [defaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"DataExists"];
                                NSLog(@"Table updated");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        sqlite3_close(db);
                        NSAssert(0, @"Could not delete records");
                    }
                    [entries removeAllObjects];

                    [vrnTable performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];

                    NSString *select = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Vehicles"];
                    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

                    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [select UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
                        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                            vehicleObject = [[Vehicle alloc] init];
                            char *vrn = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
                            NSString *vrnStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:vrn];
                            vehicleObject.vrn = vrnStr;

                            char *make = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
                            NSString *makeStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:make];
                            vehicleObject.make = makeStr;

                            char *model = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
                            NSString *modelStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:model];
                            vehicleObject.model = modelStr;

                            char *yearMade = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
                            NSString *yearMadeStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:yearMade];
                            vehicleObject.yearMade = yearMadeStr;

                            [entries addObject:vehicleObject];
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        NSAssert1(0, @"Error: Because %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
                    }

                    [self.vrnTable performSelector:@selector(reloadData) onThread:[NSThread mainThread] withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];
                    //[self removeLodingView];
                }
                else {
                    [self invalidAlert];
                }
            }
            else {
                [self invalidAlert];
            }
        }];
    }
    else {
        [self noNetworkAlert];
    }
    [_vrnTableViewController.refreshControl endRefreshing];
```

Comment: could you please add some more code to understand the problem

Comment: on nsurlconnection, the program exits the main if condition. Does not go into NSURLConnection.

Comment: if ([self hasInternetConnection] || [self hasWiFi] || [self canReachHost:@"http://myservice.asmx"]) -> have you checked all methods in if,  if all conditions or at least one of them returning true

Comment: yes. I have the same code in another method as well. and it works fine. But when I am using the same code in another method of the same class, I face the mentioned issue.

Comment: The main if condition is satisfied. Problem occurs when program tries to establish connection. Then is just exits the main if statement. but does not go into the else condition, which is correct.

Comment: What makes you sure that you are not getting any errors? You don't check the error parameter in `sendAsynchronousRequest:...`

Answer (score 0):

check all the conditions

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
    {
        NSInteger responseCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
            NSLog(@"responseCode: %d", responseCode);  //check response code

        if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)

          //data downloaded -> continue

        else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil)
            //empty reply
        else if (error != nil && error.code == ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT)
           // time out
        else if (error != nil)
            //error
    }];
```